# How to click a element on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape this page:

```
https://www.lanebryant.com/living-my-best-life-graphic-tee/prd-357900
```

I open in a browser by Selenium. There is a pop which has to be closed when the page is loaded. It closes that successfully. However, it doesn't click size guide link and gets stuck at it. 
Here is my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='closeButton']")))
close.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
chart= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='asc-groupe-size-guide']")))
chart.click()
```

Comment: give it a try with this xpath - //*[@class='size-chart-link']/a

Comment: @Sureshmani it says element is not clickable

Comment: this works just fine in chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome :/

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="mar-modal-trigger" href="#0" data-modalevent="sizeChart.open" data-modaltarget="/lanebryant/pdp/includes/contentModal.jsp?contentId=7400001" data-modalclass="mar-sizechart-modal" aria-describedby="aria-pdp-size-chart-modal" data-di-id="di-id-c192eb28-6d612ea1">...</a> is not clickable at point (106, 506). Other element would receive the click: <div id="tinymask" style="height: 1813px; width: 1017px; opacity: 0.8; display: block;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Comment: just posting my answer incase if you have missed any syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath

```
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
chart= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='size-chart-link']/a")))
chart.click()
```

or

```
time.sleep(3)
    chart= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(*,'Size Guide')][@class='size-chart-link']")))
        chart.click()
```

Comment: updated answer - As in the error message, the other element (tinymask) is receiving this click. I would try with adding additional wait. Also try with different xpath rather than using anchor element.